# Why popstate doesnt fire my function when back button is clicked? (mobile ios chrome)

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, reactjs, google-chrome

I'm trying to do that when the link is opened in new tab, there would able back to referrer page through back button.

```
const referrer = document.referrer;
const redirect = (e) => {
     if(e.state.goBack){
        window.location.href = window.location.href;
     }
 }

const _location = window.location.href
history.replaceState({goBack: true}, null, referrer);
history.pushState({}, null, _location);

window.addEventListener('popstate', redirect);
```

works fine in MacBook, android chrome/firefox.
Only in iPhone/iPad, it doesn't work. It just returns to himself. Even if I add an alert in redirect function it doesn't show up when I click the back button in iPad chrome. :(

Feels like back button click on iPad doesn't fire redirect function.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/59xwafa3/3/

Comment: on ipad, when i click the back button alert doesn't show up :(

Answer (score 2):

I've run into the same issue. The work around I've found is not to use replaceState but pushState instead: https://jsfiddle.net/6dayLhzs/1

```
const referrer = document.referrer;
const redirect = (e) => {
    if(e.state.goBack){
        window.location.href = window.location.href;
    }
 }

const _location = window.location.href
history.pushState({goBack: true}, null, referrer);
history.pushState({}, null, _location);

window.addEventListener('popstate', redirect);
```